# Ubuntu 15.10 detects a not-present display in monitor settings

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, settings

I have an Asus K53SC that has Ubuntu 15.10 installed, and in monitor settings it detects a not really present second monitor called `Unknown Display`.
Sometimes it enabled automatically itself, and I have to disable it to prevent the mouse being stuck in the other "false" monitor.

How can I disable it definitely and don't showing it anymore in settings also?

[image: display settings]

Sorry for bad English and thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure myself (someone else will have to fill you in), but this can be fixed by changing the xorg configuration files in some way.